# Modeling sympoms and diseases

Tags: prolog

The professor asked us to build a Prolog program that will diagnose a disease based on symptoms input by the user. My database of symptoms and diseases is like this :

```
causes_of(symptom1, Disease) :-
    Disease = disease1;
    Disease = disease2.
causes_of(symptom2, Disease) :-
    Disease = disease3;
    Disease = disease4.
causes_of(symptom3, Disease) :-
    Disease = disease4.
```

What I need is to interactively ask the user for symptoms and at the same time filter possible diseases, until I have no more symptoms to verify. Then I will present the user with a list of possible diseases.

Notice that I also need to filter out conflicting symptoms. To illustrate this, take the relations defined above and consider at a certain point the user has symptom2.  If this happens, I should no longer ask if the user has symptom1, because there are no diseases that cause symptom1 and symptom2 at the same time.

I don't know if I modeled the rules correctly for this, if not please point me in the right direction.

Comment: I just need help modeling what I described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the animal guessing example:

http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_17.html

It solves basically the same problem you have for your homework.